# update query not working in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, special-characters, sql-update

my problem is unable to update data because of special character single quote (') in sq-lite database. 
i want update data but special character(') single quote in string give error into sq-lite database in android how to update.
The Query is :

```
update pollm set dt_lastaccessedon='null',tx_choice1responsecount='1',tx_choice2responsecount='0',tx_choice3responsecount='0',tx_choice4responsecount='0',tx_choice5responsecount='0',tx_userresponse='TX_OPTION2',tx_questiontext='Is BPM mandatory?',tx_title='BPM',tx_choice1='yes',tx_choice2='no',tx_choice3='don't know', tx_choice4='null',tx_choice5='null',dt_availfrom='2011-07-08 00:00:00.0',dt_availto='2011-07-09 00:00:00.0',tx_status='Closed' where lmspollid='321'
```

in above query the problem is single quote in  "don't know" this string. because of this query not working. please help me

Comment: Look at my modified answer. Now you have 3 choices... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

You should be using the method update instead of generating the SQL yourself. The built-in methods will do all the needed escaping for you.

Look at [Android - SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

This not only solves your quotes problem but also mitigates **SQL Injection**.

**2.**

Form here [SQLite - Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14)

**(14) How do I use a string literal that contains an embedded single-quote (') character?**

The SQL standard specifies that single-quotes in strings are escaped by putting two single quotes in a row. SQL works like the Pascal programming language in the regard. SQLite follows this standard. Example:

```
        INSERT INTO xyz VALUES('5 O''clock');
```

**3.**

Use [DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html). The string is enclosed by single quotes and the single quotes inside the string become double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for such use full info.